# Cross Entropy for Soft Labeling in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, cross-entropy

i'm trying to define the loss function of a two-class classification problem. However, the target label is not hard label 0,1, but a float number between 0~1.

torch.nn.CrossEntropy in Pytorch do not support soft label so i'm trying to write a cross entropy function by my self.

My function looks like this

```
def cross_entropy(self, pred, target):
    loss = -torch.mean(torch.sum(target.flatten() * torch.log(pred.flatten())))
    return loss

def step(self, batch: Any):
    x, y = batch
    logits = self.forward(x)
    loss = self.criterion(logits, y)
    preds = logits
    # torch.argmax(logits, dim=1)
    return loss, preds, y
```

however it does not work at all.

Can anyone give me a suggestion is there any mistake in my loss function?

Comment: Don't post screenshot of codes. Paste the codes in your question and format it well

Comment: sure, I already  added

Answer (score 2):

It seems like [`BCELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.10.0/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html#torch.nn.BCELoss) and the robust version [`BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.10.0/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) are working with fuzzy targets "out of the box". They do not expect `target` to be binary" any number between zero and one is fine.
Please read the doc.